# Searching for Anterior Cruciate Ligament MRI Images for Finite Element Model.

Tags: finite-element-method, biomedical-engineering

I'm searching for 3D MRI images for generating an mesh to be used in a Finite Element Modeling project. My group has access to a low-resolution CT scan and cadaver knees, but we don't have any good MRI scans. I'm hoping that there might be a public repository of MRI anatomical images somewhere. Any pointers?

If not, how acceptable is it to ask to loan out CT time. This is an unfunded graduate project, so the scan would have to be pro-bono.

Comment: Have you tried the Visible Human Dataset? Not an MRI resource, but it's open for anyone to use, and being a series of colour photographs it's much more detailed than any MRI/CT scans. If your group has the expertise to isolate the Anterior Cruciate Ligament in a full colour photograph of an entire cross-section of the leg near the knee area then you're all sorted - otherwise consider a software like [TolTech](http://www.toltech.net/anatomy-software/solutions/vh-dissector-for-undergraduate-education), which will provide masks of the anatomical object you're looking for. ($79 for 2 years)